# R: Why `class(mydate) = NULL`?

Tags: r, date

I am working on date and time in R.

```
mydate = c(as.POSIXlt(as.Date(mydate$date)))
class(mydate[1])
names(mydate[1])
mydate[1]$m

class(mydate[1])
[1] "POSIXlt" "POSIXt" # As expected
names(mydate[1])
NULL # Why
mydate[1]$m
NULL # Why
```

I am not sure why can I get the month and even `names` doesn't work. The `class` shows expected output.

Update:

1. I want to access the month in the date.
2. I am following the example from [here](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~s133/dates.html)

> The individual components of a POSIX date/time object can be extracted
>   by first converting to POSIXlt if necessary, and then accessing the
>   components directly:
>
> ```
> > mydate = as.POSIXlt('2005-4-19 7:01:00')
> > names(mydate)
> [1] "sec"   "min"   "hour"  "mday"  "mon"   "year"  
> [7] "wday"  "yday"  "isdst"
> > mydate$mday
> [1] 19
> ```

Comment: Fyi, it's always better to make a reproducible example than to show us some oblique reflection of an example. Anyway, `x = as.POSIXlt(Sys.Date())` seems to illustrate the same thing. Not sure why you expect `names` or `$m` to give something here.

Comment: `class(mydate[[1]])`

Comment: @Frank See the updates. The example in the update is reproducible.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the update. When I run the code in the quote block at the end, I do not see names or $m either. It could be that that 2006 document is no longer correct.

Comment: Hm, actually, maybe it is a bug..? When I look at `?names.POSIXlt` and run the example with `names` there, I also see NULL.

Comment: From [the comment here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/library/base/R/datetime.R#L1025) it seems that `names` did not use to have a `POSIXlt` method (and, thus, just returned the names of the underlying "list") and, as Frank notes, the documentation might be missing to note the change. `$m` does not work because "m" is partially matched to more than one element -- `mydate$mon` works.